# Use of unassigned local variable in while condition and 'Cannot write to a closed TextWriter.'

Tags: c#

I tried this code but keep getting use of unassigned local variable MAX_VALUE at the while condition.(That's fixed now) But now getting 'Cannot write to a closed TextWriter.' for the WriteLine to output file.
Please help

```
    private void buttonCalculate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        double kmph;
        double MAX_VALUE;

        if (double.TryParse(textBoxSpeed.Text, out kmph) && (double.TryParse(textBoxHours.Text, out MAX_VALUE)))

        outputFile = File.CreateText("Output.txt");

        int count = 1;

        while (count <= MAX_VALUE)
        {
            outputFile.WriteLine("After hour " + count + "the distance traveled is " + kmph * count + "Km.");

            count = count + 1;

            outputFile.Close();

            MessageBox.Show("Outputs are saved to Output.txt file.");
        }
    }

    private void buttonExit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
```

Comment: Aren't you missing braces after your `if (double.TryParse(...` statement?

Comment: If `double.TryParse(textBoxSpeed.Text, out kmph)` returns false `MAX_VALUE` will not have any value assigned. That's why you are getting this message. I think you should declare `double MAX_VALUE = 0.0;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing `{` after the if statement so your code that uses the unassigned variable will always be executed and throw an exception:

```
        //I'm not sure if you want to continue writing or every time you enter the function rewrite the file...
        //This is an example in case you want to continue writing
        var filePath = "C:\\myPath";
        if (!File.Exists(filePath))
        {
            //If file doesn't exist create one
            File.CreateText(filePath);
        }

        var outputFile = File.AppendText(filePath); //open file to write

        if (double.TryParse(textBoxSpeed.Text, out kmph) && (double.TryParse(textBoxHours.Text, out MAX_VALUE)))
        {

            outputFile = File.CreateText("Output.txt");

            int count = 1;

            while (count <= MAX_VALUE)
            {
                outputFile.WriteLine("After hour " + count + "the distance traveled is " + kmph * count + "Km.");

                count = count + 1;


                MessageBox.Show("Outputs are saved to Output.txt file.");
            }

            outputFile.Flush();
            outputFile.Close();
        }
```

Comment: I see what I missed Thank you but now the program doesn't want to write lines in the output file. I get this message 'Cannot write to a closed TextWriter.'

Comment: @Anastasia This is because you close the `outputfile` after the first iteration of the while loop. I edited my anwser and put the `Close()` after the while . Go take a look and tell me if it worked :)

Comment: @Anastasia You could use a for loop instead of a while loop and count the iterations inside... But its just a matter of taste

Comment: @Anastasia are you sure that you have checked the right path? Pass the whole path and not just a file name. Should I edit the answer?

Comment: @Anastasia I found the error... You need to do a `outputFile.Flush();` before you close the file. Did it work?

Comment: @Anastasia I edited my answer so your code should work as you want. Be sure to change the path variable and you should be ready to go :)